# What rarity is the Shadowsong bow in AL play, after the Content Catalog v9 update?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, dnd-adventurers-league

The published Dungeons &Dragons 5th Edition adventure [DDEX3-07 Herald of the Moon](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170501/DDEX307-Herald-of-the-Moon-5e) awards a magic item called *Shadowsong*.

In the original adventure, *Shadowsong* is a very rare modified *Oathbow* (bold for emphasis mine):

> #### Shadowsong (Oathbow)
>
> *Weapon (longbow), **very rare** (requires attunement by a ranger)*
>
> Each of the elven oathbows are possessed of mythical power and ancient legends. Shadowsong is hewn from a supple length of yew and features curious green metal tendrils snaking through its length. It glows dimly in the presence of humans. The description of this item can be found in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*.

In Adventurers League play, after the [Content Catalog v9](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack) update (p. 28), this bow was changed to a *+2 weapon* (bold for emphasis mine):

> #### DDEX03-07 Herald of the Moon
>
> This adventure features an item that is no longer acceptable under D&D Adventurers League guidelines, as it deviates from the attunement standards in the DMG. **Instead of *Shadowsong*, this adventure instead unlocks a *+2 weapon (longbow or shortbow)*. This *+2 weapon* has the sentinel property and glows dimly in the presence of humans.**

A *+2 weapon* is rare, not very rare.

**So, taking into account this change, what rarity is *Shadowsong*?**

The content catalog doesn't mention the rarity.
Does this mean that it is unchanged, and still "very rare"?
Or should it be the rarity of a usual *+2 weapon*, and thus just "rare" instead?

Comment: Related: [How does the Shadowsong bow deviate from the attunement standards?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/198361/33569)

Answer (score 7):

### The bow you receive is Rare

Because of the phrasing of the note in the Content Catalog (p. 28), players don't receive a bow called "Shadowsong" at all:

> **Instead of *Shadowsong***, this adventure instead unlocks a *+2 weapon (longbow or shortbow)*. This *+2 weapon* has the sentinel property and glows dimly in the presence of humans.

They instead receive a *+2 weapon* which has an additional minor property. This *+2 weapon* doesn't have a name, which seems a bit odd since it has an additional property.

A *+2 weapon* is rare, and adding a minor property doesn't change that.

So, players don't receive the very rare bow *Shadowsong*, they receive a rare *+2 weapon* with an additional minor property.